# Не отображются файлы необходимого расширения

Tags: c#, .net

Не отображает файлы необходимого расширения.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFile.Filter = "Files|*.zip,*.rar";
    openFile.ShowDialog();

    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = openFile.FileName;
    }
}
```

В чем загвоздка?

Comment: А зачем два раза подряд `ShowDialog`?

Comment: @VladD не силен в c#, пытаюсь немного освоить, поэтому ответить ничего не могу.

Comment: @rnddev: Правильный ответ: не нужно. Ну или разве что вы хотите, чтобы диалог показывался два раза.

Comment: @VladD намек понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `;` вместо `,` для разделителя фильтра.

[Документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) гласит:

> You can add several filter patterns to a filter by separating the file types with **semicolons**...